# RabbitMq connection failed exception on production server

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, .net-4.6.2

I have a windows forms application that is built on .NET 4.6.2. I'm connecting the app to rabbitmq using below code. Rabbit mq services are deployed on a separate server.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = _host, Port = _port, UserName = _userName, Password = _password };
if (_port != 5672){
factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
factory.Ssl.Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
factory.Ssl.CertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };}
Client = factory.CreateConnection();
Channel = Client.CreateModel();
```

This is working completely fine in production. Now recently we were planning a new release where there were changes in other components but no changes in this app however when I run the app on production server it gives below exception.

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.IO.IOException: connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open(Boolean insist)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IFrameHandler fh)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at LiveStatisticsBroker.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus() in LiveStatistics.cs:line 105
```

There are no changes in the code and if I revert to the previous release it works fine. I have checked network connectivity and there are no issues even if I telnet the server IP and with port 5671 it gets succeeded.

Strange thing is If I place same release on development server rabbitmq gets connected. Our development servers also follow same network rules. I have been stuck on this for some time and couldn't get any success.

Comment: You skip the certificate check in production as well?

Comment: Hi @MaxNaumov Yes I know this can cause security issues but for now we have skipped it.

Comment: It can be anything. If you haven't already did it 1. Check if rabbit is running and can access it's ui. Check rabbit logs. 2. Double check the firewall rules both server and client.

Comment: I can access UI from both, the server where Rabbitmq is hosted and the one where Im deploying the app and its accessible with the credentials I have provided in the connection factory. I have checked the firewall rules as well. i haven't checked rabbitmq logs but the error is on Client = factory.CreateConnection(); so I don't think it reaches rabbitmq yet no?

Comment: Error indicates the connection never completed.  Most likely it is failing the TLS with the certificate.  Net 4.6.2 does not support all encryption methods that may be used by the certificate.  Starting with Net 4.7.1 TLS is performed by the operating system.  Prior it is done inside Net.  There were issues with encryption in Net 4.6.2 that is did not work with all encryption modes.  The versions of TLS is 1.2 and 1.3.  Server could be set to use only 1.3 which would cause a failure.  OR certificate is 1.3.  Or certificate encryption mode is not supported in Net 4.6.2

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I have checked both servers and Server protocols, Client protocols, Ciphers and Hashes all are exactly same. Only in Key exchanges the development server has all enabled why on production server PKCS is disabled. Could this cause the issue?

Comment: Yes.  It depends on the encryption method in the certificate.  If PKCS is the encryption method in the certificate, disabling will prevent connection from completing.  PKCS encryption is no longer uses because it can easily be decrypted by hackers.  Using a different certificate that does use PKCS may solve issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help so far @jdweng. We created a separated certificate for rabbitmq can you let me know how to check the encryption method? I can't seem to find it. I can see the .pem files

Comment: PEM file contains only the keys.  The certificate contains more info than the pem.

Comment: Update for you @jdweng our rabbitmq certificate uses PKCS #1 SHA-256 With RSA Encryption. So do I need to enable PKCS on the server where rabbitmq is installed or the production server from where Im connecting to the Rabbitmq?

Comment: Both client and server needs to be able to encrypt/decrypt using the certificate.  The key in the certificate is used to encrypt/decrypt the data in the connection.  So both ends of connection needs to use the algorithm.  Make sure you are using TLS 1.2 (not TLS 1.3).  Issue could be you are setting only TLS 1.3 instead of both 1.2 and 1.3, 
 See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng currently PKCS is disabled on both client and server. Im not sure how this was working before certificate is same, but I can have PKCS enabled on both if that could be the issue. Edit : We have only Tls1.2 enabled on both servers.

Comment: Hi @jdweng thanks for your help I found the solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading RabbitMq.Client nuget package from 6.2.1 to 6.5.0 did the trick for me. System.Memory was also upgraded as a dependency.